# Javascript use dom to add data to a table

Tags: javascript, dom, row, addition

I have two tables one with an add button and one without an add button. How can I take the data I enter into the row with the add button and get it to appear in the other table? For example if I fill in 1,2,3 etc. and click add the table will be updated to row 1 having 5,4,6. row 2 having 1,2,3. and then if I add a third row it would go underneath row 2.

Here is an example of what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/r8yXp/4/

I just am not sure how to get the data from the input fields into the table above when the add button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly simplified answer but you can use this one as a basis for what you're trying to do:

```
Name:​<input type="text" id="name">
<input type="button" id="add" value="add"/>
<br/>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
    </th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody id="root"></tbody>
</table>
<script>
    $('#add').click(function(){
    var name = $('#name').val(); //get value from text field
    var root = $('#root'); //this is where you will attached the new row
    var tr = $("<tr>"); //the new row
    var td = $("<td>").text(name); //use text from textfield as the text for the new table row
    td.appendTo(tr);
    tr.appendTo(root);
    });
</script>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Here's the link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jrPxr/

To generate inputs:

```
var input = $("<input>").attr({"type" : "text", "id" : "someID"}).val(name);
```

Then just append it to its direct parent. In this case the table definition:

```
input.appendTo(td);
```

You can just change the type to whatever input you want(radio, checkbox,etc..)

Comment: How do I place the inputs into a table too? so that it would be <table><tr><th>Name</th></tr><td><input /></td></table>

Comment: I've updated the answer. Basically you just have to generate an input field and supply the value from user input.

Comment: how can I have both of them in a table? the data being typed in with the add button and the data that is being added. so that there would be two tables

Comment: like this: <table><tr><td>Name:​<input type="text" id="name"> <input type="button" id="add" value="add"/></td></tr></table> <br/> <table border="1">     <tr>     </th>Name</th>     </tr>     <tbody id="root"></tbody> </table> <script>     $('#add').click(function(){     var name = $('#name').val(); //get value from text field     var root = $('#root'); //this is where you will attached the new row     var tr = $("<tr>"); //the new row     var td = $("<td>").text(name); //use text from textfield as the text for the new table row     td.appendTo(tr);     tr.appendTo(root);     }); </script>

Comment: How do you get the value of the radio button from the add row to the copied row?

Comment: $("input[name=NAME OF YOUR RADIO BUTTON]:checked").val();